# Laravel : How to show form error feedback of input that `type='file'`?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel `5.5` and bootstrap `4.0-beta` .

How to show form error feedback of input that `type='file'`?

If input `type='text'`,I can show error feedback like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="username" class="col-2 col-form-label">username:</label>
    <div class="col-10">
        <input id="username" name="username" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" value="{{ old('username') }}">
        @if ($errors->has('username'))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

**question:**

If input `type='file'`, how to show error feedback? The code below does not work.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="photo" class="col-2 col-form-label">photo:</label>
    <div class="col-10">
    <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo">
        @if ($errors->has('photo'))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('photo') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your photo actually being uploaded? What does your `<form>` element look like? What does your validation function look like in your controller? We need more information.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try adding `is-invalid` class to the input.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="photo" class="col-2 col-form-label">photo:</label>
    <div class="col-10">
    <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('photo') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">
        @if ($errors->has('photo'))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('photo') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but there is no the error text infomation, that is,there is no `{{ $errors->first('photo') }}`

Comment: You can show the message by adding `form-control` to file input.

Comment: I mean `<div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('photo') }}</div>` not shown